# Can't connect to Oracle 11g via JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect my JSF application to my Oracle 11g database.  A while back I had a JSF application connecting a similar way with a Derby database.  Around the same time I was able to connect to an Oracle 11g database via a Java program I wrote.

I've tried to port the code into this recent project, and while everything looks correct, my connection in the code is returning null.

To further this issue, NetBeans seems to lock up when I try to debug.  I'm assuming it goes to use the port that is running GlassFish 4, but somehow can't tell its occupied.

Any help is appreciated; please let me know if I can provide further information that I somehow overlooked.

Code snippets as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(name="OracleBean")
@RequestScoped
public class OracleBean {

    private String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8081:xe";
    private String dbName = "test";
    private String dbUsername = "Username";
    private String dbPassword = "password";
    private Connection connect = null;

    private OracleMethods Method;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of DataBean
     */
    public OracleBean() {
        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8081:xe";
        dbName = "Test";
        dbUsername = "Username";
        dbPassword = "password";
        connect = null;

        Method = new OracleMethods();
    }

    public String getColorData(String rowID, int col) {
        connect = Method.getConnection(driver, url, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        if (connect == null) {
            return "SQL Error";
        }
```

//end Bean code

```
public class OracleMethods extends JPanel {

    private Connection connect = null;

    public OracleMethods() {}

    public Connection getConnection(String driver, String url, String dbName, String dbUsername, String dbPassword) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection((url + dbName), dbUsername, dbPassword);
        } catch (Exception lex) {
            lex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connect;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Please post `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: Don't initialize your instance variables in two places. Either in the declarations or in the `OracleBean` constructor, not both. Also there are two `OracleDriver` classes in the jar, one in `oracle.jdbc` and one in `oracle.jdbc.driver` - I'm pretty sure you want the first one instead of the one you're using.

Comment: @A.L I can't seem to debug without glassfish locking up, so I'm not sure where to look for the error.  As you can see in the code snippet, if the connect object is null, then it returns "SQL Error" to the webpage, that's as much as an indication that I have at the moment.

Comment: @RomanC I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Kamurai Why are you using non standard port to connect to the database?

Comment: @gknicker No joy swapping the reference name, but that does make me wonder if I actually have the .jar referenced properly at all.

Comment: I fixed the reference to the odbc14.jar file.  It takes a lot longer to fail, but at least I know it's attempting the connection now.

Comment: I'll clarify the variables being assigned twice, even if it doesn't seem to be relevant, its initialized that way so I have a clean copy of what used to work, but the rest of the object can reference those variables.  It is set in the constructor with the values I need to apply as they over write the initialization.

This is a web application written with JSF, not a standalone.  There might be code left over from the old stand alone program the last time I had a working Oracle connection.

Comment: The method called "getConnection" is just to open a db connection to execute whatever else.

Once I have a working example I will streamline it to be used as infrequently as possible / is sensible.

All the current objective is to pull the colors of the rainbow from the oracle db and display them on a page.

Comment: Update: I've revitalized the old standalone program I had that previously connected to the Oracle 11g succesffully.  So the database is reachable and readable.

I also shut down glassfish and manage to launch a debugged session of the application.

The line that fails is the DriveManager line.

I also manage to see the session start through the Oracle 11g webinterface, so it is reaching Oracle in theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests and force deploying the application a few times (though it would show coding changes without this), the following syntax ended up working:

```
public OracleBean()
{
    driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    dbName = "Test";
    dbUsername = "username";
    dbPassword = "password";
    connect = null;

    Method = new OracleMethods();
}

public String getColorData(String rowID, int col)
{
    connect = Method.openConnection(driver, url, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

//end bean code

```
public Connection openConnection(String driver, String url, String dbName, String dbUsername, String dbPassword)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
            System.out.println("Could not load the driver");
    }

    try
    {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection((url), dbUsername, dbPassword);
    }
    catch(Exception lex)
    {
        lex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above - are you sure the db is running on port 8081 and not 1521 as standard. Also is the dbname Test or XE as you have in the url. I suspect it's xe if you have the standard setup.

The following should get you a connection assuming you have the oracle driver jar as an external library

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "your_user", "your_password");
```

Comment: I forgot about that, when I got the stand alone to connect to the db, it was on port 1521, but I'm still having trouble getting the JSF to connect with the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you your error is that you are concatenating url and dbname, and it should be just the url as you are connectiong to instance xe and not xeTest
instead of

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection((url+dbName), dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

use

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection((url), dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

Comment: so in the end it was this and the connection port?

Comment: It was the .jar file being properly referenced, the port, the url and using Netbeans / glassfish properly to deploy the project.